# Proving that the expansion of a convex set is convex

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I am trying to solve problem 2.14 from Stephen Boyd's 'Convex Optimization', which is as follows.

Given a convex set $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, a norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and a constant $a \geq 0$, we have to prove that the set
$$ S_a = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : d(x,S) \leq a \}, $$
is convex, where $d(x,S)$ is the distance between $x$ and $S$, defined as
$$ d(x,S) = \inf_{y \in S} \ \lVert x - y \rVert. $$

So, I take two points $x_1, x_2 \in S_a$, a constant $\alpha \in [0,1]$, denote $\alpha x_1 + (1-\alpha)x_2$ by $x$, and get
$$ d(x,S) = \inf_{y \in S} \ \lVert \alpha x_1 + (1-\alpha) x_2 - y \rVert
\leq \inf_{y \in S} \left[ \alpha \lVert (x_1-y) \rVert + (1-\alpha) \lVert (x_2-y) \rVert \right] $$
by the triangle inequality, but I am stuck here. I feel I am missing a trick since I can't figure out how to use the convexity of $S$. Any help will be greatly appreciated. (This is not a homework question BTW.)

Comment: Maybe you can write $y$ as $\alpha y_1 + (1- \alpha)y_2$ where $y_1$ and $y_2$ are chosen as $y_i = \arg \min_{y \in S} d(x_i , S)$. It looks like this works out form there.

Comment: If the convex set is not closed, these minima are not necessarily attained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Take $\epsilon > 0$ arbitrary. Since $x_1, x_2 \in S_a$, there are two points $y_1$ and $y_2$ in $S$ such that $\|x_1- y_1\| <a + \epsilon$ and $\|x_2 - y_2\|<a + \epsilon$. We want to show that there is a point $z$ in $S$ such that $\|\alpha x_1 + (1-\alpha)x_2 - z\| <a+\epsilon$. A natural candidate is the point $z=\alpha y_1 + (1-\alpha)y_2$ and by convexity of $S$ this point belongs to $S$.
So you want to show
$$
  \|\alpha x_1 +(1-\alpha)x_2 - (\alpha y_1 +(1-\alpha)y_2 )\| <a + \epsilon.
$$
Use the inequalities $\|x_1- y_1\| <a+\epsilon$ and $\|x_2 - y_2\|<a+\epsilon$ for this.

After this is proven, use that $\epsilon>0$ can be taken arbitrarily small and conclude.

Comment: If $x_1,x_2$ are such that $d(x_1,S)=a$ and $d(x_2,S)=a$, then the property in the first line need not hold (for example, if $S$ is an open set such as the unit open disk). Nevertheless, your answer was useful since it helped me come up with the following solution. Denoting the closure of $S$ by $\bar{S}$, we can prove that $d(x,S) = d(x,\bar{S})$ for any $x$. So we can rewrite $S_a$ in terms of distances to $\bar{S}$ instead of distances to $S$. Now let $y_1,y_2$ be the projections of $x_1,x_2$ onto $\bar{S}$, and then proceed as in your answer. Marking your answer as accepted.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta I see! For some reason I was mistakenly thinking that $S_a$ is defined as $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid d(x,S) < a\}$ (strict inequality). I added some $\epsilon > 0$ in my answer to fix this. So the global idea remains basically the same: "If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are at a distance less then $a+\epsilon$ from the set $S$,  then the points on the line segment must also lie at a distance less then $a$ plus a bit."